# Bash Script - Filter out lines with Timestamp of last 1HR

Tags: bash, timestamp

Trying to filter lines in file by comparing the first two columns with (current time - 1 Hour)

**File Data:**

```
09:38:41 AM col3 col4 ...
11:32:00 AM col3 col4 ...
11:58:48 AM col3 col4 ...
12:00:01 AM col3 col4 ...
12:55:58 PM col3 col4 ...
01:51:56 PM col3 col4 ...
02:26:40 PM col3 col4 ...
03:18:54 PM col3 col4 ...
```

So, if the time of execution is **14:01:00**, it should fetch lines between **13:00:00** to **13:59:59**, so only below is fetched.

```
01:51:56 PM col3 col4 ...
```

Not sure about the condition to be applied, this is my basic progress:

```
varDataFile="fileName.txt"
varCurTime=$(date +"%I:%M:%S %p")

while read line
do
    varCurLine=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1 " " $2}')
    if [[ <condition>]]; then
        echo $Line
    fi
done < $varDataFile
```

Comment: So, basically, you only need to look at the _hour_ part, not the _minutes_ and _seconds_? In this case, you don't need to manually loop through the files. Instead calculate the current hour, subtract one from it (be careful with the first hour past midnight!) and then use `grep` to extract the lines according to the calculated hour.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks alot! It was so simple, didnt think of it. Awesome! Got it working.

Answer (score 1):

If your file *only* has HH:MM:SS (even with AM/PM) it's going to fail just after midnight when the system assumes the current day and reads some of the lines as being in the future. Other than that...

If the file isn't large, I like to convert all date/time values to seconds since the epoch for simple comparisons.

```
now=$(date +%s)
while read t ap x
do l=$(date --date="$t$ap" +%s)
(( 3600>(now-l) )) && echo "$t $ap $x"
done
```

A `read` and a `date` on every line of a huge file might add up to be problematic, though.

For a really big file you'd do better using something like `awk`, in which case I hope you have access to the time functions.